# Camera Controller in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There are two similar scripts that makes the same thing(The Camera is following the player).The first, is what I wrote and the second one, is from the unity tutorial.Which one is more reliable and why?

1st

```
   public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour {

   public GameObject player;

   void LateUpdate () {

    transform.position = new Vector3 (player.transform.position.x,  player.transform.position.y,-10f);

   }
   }
```

2nd

```
    public GameObject player;       

    private Vector3 offset;

    void Start () 
    {
    offset = transform.position - player.transform.position;
    }

    void LateUpdate () 
    {

    transform.position = player.transform.position + offset;
    }
```

Comment: Just like your other questions, this is C# not unityscript. Just saying this so that you will understand when asking your next question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as reliability between the two scripts. Although, I would encourage you to use the *second* script.

The **first** script is assigning the camera's position with the position of the player. The only thing it doesn't assign is the z-axis which you hard-coded to `-10`. When game starts, the camera will be moved to where the player is. The z- axis of the camera will be set to `-10`. This happens every late update.

The **second** script is assigning the camera's position with the position of the player *and offset value taken in the `start` function*. When game starts, the offset distance between the camera and the player is retrieved in the `Start` function. In the `LateUpdate` function, the player's position is retrieved and the offset is added to it and is then applied to the camera's position.

---

The result of the first script is that the camera will always be position where the player is but the z axis will always be set to `-10`. I am sure you don't want the z axis to not be moving.

The result of the second script is that the camera will *always have the-same distance between it and the player*. Even if you move the camera or player from the Editor, the second script *will automatically adjust the position and make sure that the distance between the camera and the player before the game started is always the-same*. I am sure this is what you are looking for but I wouldn't call this reliable. The first code is simply not appropriate for what you are doing , the second code is.

Comment: It's 2D game so I wrote -10 to z axis

Comment: That makes sense since it's 2D. That piece of code is originally from the roll ball game tutorial from Unity which is 3D so my answer is based on 3D. Everything else I said is still true except for the z-axis which doesn't matter here. You need the offset for the x and y  values so the second code wins

Comment: That's also from UFO 2D Tutorial!

Comment: Yes it is also in the 2D tutorial. Although it was originally made for the 3D roll ball game then they re-used it for the 2D tutorial. Just checked the timeline of each tutorial to verify this again.

Answer (score 1):

I would bet that the second one is more reliable because it doesn't have any hardcoded variables. But it's also easy to use to programmers and none programmers since it calculates the offSet you want to give in any direction based on the position you set on the scene.